# Windows 10 Home Edition on a T1 Line

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bandwidth

I work for a small company which has a few computers for public use. These machines are on a separate subnet, but still use the same T1 internet connection as the rest of the registers and staff computers.

Recently as a trial we decided to upgrade one of the windows 7 home machines to windows 10 - which in turn upgraded to windows 10 home. When Windows pushes out a new update this machine goes ahead and uses the full bandwidth, causing registers to hang, and other staff to have to stop work.

The only current solution I have found is a program called NetLimiter which runs as a service and simply limits traffic going in and out of this machine. Aside from NetLimiter or changing the OS are there any other options I can use to limit/restrict/stop Windows Update from destroying our bandwidth?

Comment: [Enable Metered Connection to Delay Windows 10 Updates](http://lifehacker.com/enable-metered-connection-to-delay-windows-10-updates-1723316525)

Comment: [Setup Windows to use WSUS.](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/63158-configuring-windows-7-home-premium-wsus-updates.html)  This way you use your bandwidth within your own network and you can schedule when and if an update happens.  You can add the required tool easy enough if you wanted, there is a question that exists, that explains the process.

Comment: @DavidPostill that only works for wifi connected PC's.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you, but we are all running on wired connections. WSUS is something that I will look into if I can get it to work with Home Edition!

Answer (score 0):

If the pc's are connected using wireless you can set the network connection to "metered" in each of the Windows 10 pc's. This can also be done [for Windows 8 pc's](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions)

Enter Settings from the start menu, then select Network and Internet
[image]

In the "Wi-Fi" section select Advanced Options
[image]

Then set it to a metered connection
[image]

.

.
If the PC's are connected using ethernet cables then you will have to look in your Routers firmware to see there is the ability to [configure QoS](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2689995/quality-of-service-explained-how-routers-with-strong-qos-make-better-home-networks.html)

Comment: Unfortuately PCs are using wired connection only - I had a quick look at the router for QOS but nothing jumps out. We want to eventually upgrade them all to Win10, so its something ideally we need to plan for.